# MySQL - INSERT INTO with SELECT and foreign key constraints

Tags: mysql, select, insert, key

I have a table that contains foreign key constraints. This table gets updated using an INSERT INTO ... SELECT statement.This works fine if the SELECT statement returns at least one row of data.

However, if the SELECT statement return all NULL's (ie there is no data that matches the SELECT query) the INSERT throws an error due to the foreign key constraint.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Please add your query. It's too vage otherwise.

Comment: juergen thanks for the feedback.....

Doh! I just realized the problem, I was using a LEFT JOIN which although didn't return data from all joins, returned it from just one which actually created a row of NULL values. 
Obviously the INSERT statement tried to insert that and failed
I guess I need to go back to basics and look at the join statements again...

Comment: In short, OP is asking like, not to let fail `insert into tbl(fk_field) select null ...` when `fk_field` is defined `not null`.